# How to stop Redux resets state when using window.open to redirect a URL

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, routes

I have a simple login page, when the informations are correct, I redirect the user to another url via window.open() with _self parameter. Eg: `window.open("/home", "_self");`

The problem is, I save this login information to the Redux store, but naturally Redux resets the store because of window.open()'s page load. I can't use **Link** on Login button.

So is it possible to redirect to another URL without page load (not using **Link** as I mentioned) or avoid Redux reset state action?

Answer (score 1):

You might want to use [Redux Persist](https://www.npmjs.com/package/redux-persist) which allows you to store your redux state in the local storage of your device and when your react app renders initially hydrate your redux from the redux persist **OR** you can pass in query param that indicates somethings like

> *yourURL.com?isLoggedIn=true*

and trap in the query param and render your component as needed.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I had to solve it via **Link**, giving **to** parameter's value with ternary operator.